# Non-continuity of partial derivatives of $\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Continuity of a function's partial derivatives implies differentiability of a function. However, I'm a bit confused applying this to what seems to be a common example brought up in textbooks:

Consider f where:

f(x, y) = $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ for (x, y) $\ne$ (0, 0) and 0 for (x, y) = (0, 0). Using the definition of the partial derivative, I can obtain that the partial derivatives of f are both 0 at (0, 0).

Furthermore, for (x, y) $\ne$ (0, 0), the partial derivative of f with respect to x is $\frac{y(y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$, which is clearly equal to 0 along the x axis where y = 0. Therefor the limit of this partial derivative should approach 0 as (x, y) approaches (0, 0) - I figure that since (0, 0) is the point in question, then I don't need to consider the partial derivative w.r.t x at other y values. This together with the partial derivative equalling 0 at (0, 0) should allow me to conclude that the partial derivative is continuous, no? The same should apply to the partial derivative w.r.t y by symmetry.

But I already know that f isn't differentiable at (0, 0), so I must have made a mistake somewhere. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: What happens to $f_x$ if $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ along the line $y=2x$?

Comment: @saulspatz, I see what you mean, but if  is obtained by holding y constant, how is it that we can approach on a line where y changes?

Comment: You got the value of the partial derivative to be $0$ at $(0,0)$. But is it continuous? Take your expression, and consider $y$ a non-zero constant. Set $x=0$. Then the partial derivative is $1/y$, which is not continuous as $y\to 0$

Comment: Somewhere in between I just ended up forgetting that I didn't need to lock y to 0. I see what you both mean now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the line $x=y$. Then $$f(x,x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+x^2}=\frac 12$$The function is not even continuous at $(0,0)$

Comment: True, but the OP's mistake is really that the partials aren't continuous.

Comment: I agree. I think in your comment you used the same approach.